# Dell Compellent SAN with ESXi 5.1 iSCSI

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, storage-area-network, dell, iscsi

I have a Compellent SAN that I am trying to point to my ESXi server through iSCSI.

In the Compellent UI: i've created a volume. It, of course, says the volume is offline until you map it to a server. So I selected "map volume to a server" and it lists some objects that are down the list under "servers" but none of them are my ESXi servers. So I go to "create a server" and it can't find any HBAs or anything.

Obviously I am a Compellent newcomer, but I am pretty good with VMware stuff. I have a separate virtual switch with an iSCSI software adapter. Everything seems to be working fine, though the VMs are on local storage and I really want to map this iSCSI volume to the environment.

It would really help if someone could walk me through how to do this, or point me to an easy to understand article or video (I've searched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that software iSCSI adapter visible in the Compellent Storage Manager, you have to configure the software adapter to talk to the Compellent's iSCSI card. I can't remember the exact field, but in the static tab you can add the IP address / DNS Name of the iSCSI card, and click Login. That should get the two talking to each other, and should let the Compellent know that there is a new HBA to keep track of.

Once you have that, you can create a new server and add in that newly discovered HBA.

Comment: Thanks! Explaining it that way helped a lot. I found out where the I/O cards' information was and mapped the appropriate IP address. I guess in VMware, routed iSCSI is not supported yet, so I had to assign my software iSCSI adapter a static IP on the iSCSI network for them to see each other.